# Ajax call inside a for loop works when expressed as a function but not when placed directly inside the for loop. Why?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code that loads all five images successfully:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
  (function() {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var r = "images/"+i+".jpg";
    oReq.open("GET",r, true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    oReq.send();

    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
        var blob = new Blob([oReq.response], {type: "image/jpg"});
        var x = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var img = new Image(); 
        img.src = x;
        img.width = 100;
        $("#someDiv").append(img);
        };
    })();
}
```

Here is the code that loads only the last image:

```
  for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var r = "images/"+i+".jpg";
    oReq.open("GET",r, true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    oReq.send();

    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
        var blob = new Blob([oReq.response], {type: "image/jpg"});
        var x = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var img = new Image(); 
        img.src = x;
        img.width = 100;
        $("#someDiv").append(img);
    };
}
```

Why does the callback to an asynchronous function in a for loop only work when the code is placed in a function rather than placed directly inside of the loop?

Comment: Because calling a function creates a new scope, giving each callback "its own" `oReq` variable. See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196). Without it, `oReq` will always refer to the value of the last iteration, hence `new Blob([oReq.response], {type: "image/jpg"});` always receives the response from the last request.

Comment: Note in ES6 you could get the desired behavior by declaring all your variables within the loop using `let` instead of `var`. That works for the same reason - you close over a new variable each time rather than capturing the same one in each iteration.

Comment: its because of "Scope of variables"..when you put your variables inside function (as in your case) each var has its own scope (your functions in loop) but when you use it directly its the same variable that's get overridden with new value..result you have final value as result

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, there are as many `oReq` variables as there are iterations of the loop, because each time the wrapping function is invoked (`(function() {...})()`), it creates a new scope that includes a new `oReq` variable.

In the second case, there is a single `oReq` variable that is reused and set to a new value with each iteration of the loop.

This is significant because it determines the value that `oReq` refers to when `new Blob([oReq.response], ...);` is executed in the `onload` handler. In the first case, it refers to the `oReq` local to the anonymous wrapping function, so each `onload` function refers to a unique `oReq`. In the second case, all `onload` callbacks refer to a single `oReq` value, which holds the single final value stored in `oReq`

Comment: Thanks :) Good explanation!

Comment: So why doesnt it append the final value of `oReq.response` all five times instead of giving an error 4 out of 5 times?

Comment: @Desdemona What error message does it produce in your browser's JS console?